# Passing construction to super class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, super

I was wondering if i have an abstract super class with x different constructors, and i want to be able to use all those constructors in a subclass, do i have to write all x constructors in the subclass and just let them all call super(...) ? Seems like redundant code..

An example for the clarity:

```
public class SuperClass {
public SuperClass() {
...
}
public SuperClass(double d) {
...
}
public SuperClass(BigDecimal b) {
...
}
public SuperClass(BigDecimal b, String s) {
...
}
[...]
}
```

Do i than need:

```
public class SuperClass {
public SubClass() {
super();
}
public SubClass(double d) {
super(d);
}
public SubClass(BigDecimal b) {
super(b);
}
public SuperClass(BigDecimal b, String s) {
super(b, s);
}
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But you have to do it this way. As this way you are deciding what you want to expose in the subclass. Also some constructors might be not appropriate for a sub class thus this is not working by default without you coding it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to supply constructors for every overload of base's constructors. You simply need one. If your base constructor offers a default (parameterless) constructor, then you do not even need to provide a constructor yourself. The compiler will automatically generate a default constructor for your class that automatically calls the default constructor of your base class.

Note: it is not necessary to call `super()` directly, as it is implied without parameters. It is only required when no default constructor exists.

Seeing that many different constructors, and the fact that you do not need them all *might* imply that the parent class is doing too much.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a code like this:

```
public class SuperClass {
public SuperClass() {
...
}
public SuperClass(double d) {
...
}
public SuperClass(BigDecimal b) {

}
public SuperClass(BigDecimal b, String s) {
this(b);
}
[...]
}
```

And have a subclass as:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
public SubClass() {
super();
}
public SubClass(double d) {
super(d);
}

public SuperClass(BigDecimal b, String s) {
super(b, s);
}
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want every type of constructor in both parenr and child, then yes, you need to specify them explicitly, but no need to call `super()` explicitly.